# Error Retrieving Dialog Result and Chosen Value From DataGridViewCellEvent to MouseEventArgs

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to pass the dialog result and selected value from the data grid view from my second form to my main form. I am recieving the error "'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs'.

Main Form:

```
Private Sub btnSearchByState_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchByState.Click
        Try
            Dim newStateForm As New frmFindCustomerByState
            Dim selectedButton As DialogResult = newStateForm.ShowDialog()
            If selectedButton = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                txtFillByCustomerID.Text = frmFindCustomerByState.Tag.ToString
            End If
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server error # " & ex.Number & ": " & ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Second Form:

```
Private Sub CustomersDataGridView_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles CustomersDataGridView.DoubleClick
        Try
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = e.RowIndex
            If rowIndex = -1 Then
                rowIndex = 0
            End If
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow = CustomersDataGridView.Rows(rowIndex)
            Dim cell As DataGridViewCell = row.Cells(0)
            Dim customerID As Integer = CInt(cell.Value)

            Me.Tag = customerID
            Me.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
        Catch ex As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show("SQL Server error # " & ex.Number & ": " & ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

When the button "Find Customer By State" is selected in the main form, the second form should open. Once a state is entered and customers are displayed in the data grid table, the user should be able to double click on a row and display that customer data in the main form. I've seen some dislike for the "tag" property, but I am required to use it for this assignment. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking that the default form instance of `frmFindCustomerByState` is the same instance as `newStateForm`. When you instantiate an *instance* of `frmFindCustomerByState` via the `newStateForm` variable, it is the `newStateForm` instance that has the `.Tag` set.

This fix is:

```
Private Sub btnSearchByState_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearchByState.Click
    Try

        Dim newStateForm As New frmFindCustomerByState
        Dim selectedButton As DialogResult = newStateForm.ShowDialog()
        
        If selectedButton = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then

            'txtFillByCustomerID.Text = frmFindCustomerByState.Tag.ToString
            ' This is the fix:
            txtFillByCustomerID.Text = newStateForm.Tag.ToString

        End If

    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show("SQL Server error # " & ex.Number & ": " & ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Also, fix your error message to show something more appropriate. It looks like you just copy-and-pasted from a function that connects to SQL Server.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Also yes, I was just filling it in until I got back to it later.